# Repositories of funded research projects in different countries?

Tags: research-process, funding, repository

I am looking for different national repositories (US, Canada, Australia, UK, etc.) of funded research projects, similar to what **[Cordis](http://www.cordis.europa.eu/projects/home_en.html)** does in EU. Any suggestions?

I am after any repository that list funded research and some of the projects details, whether it is public, private or partnership...

Comment: Do you want just public, or private research groups as well?

Comment: @damien I am after any repository that list funded research and some of the projects details, public/private or partnership...

Comment: I am now voting to close this question since the bounty makes it is clear that this is a poll question.

Comment: @DanielE.Shub This is not a poll question. It can easily be turned to a wiki of sorts for everyone to use and one brave person can compile a comprehensive list (and that is the reason for the bounty).

Comment: @blackace "I would like to draw attention to it and get more answers in regards to other countries/sources" is the definition of a poll question.

Comment: @DanielE.Shub "The current answers does not contain enough detail" is the selected reason for the bounty and the extra bit you quoted is extra detail that you have interpreted differently.

Comment: @DanielE.Shub In case you still think its a poll question I suggest you edit it to a more acceptable form as I think we can all use this if other interesting answers are added rather than closing it.

Comment: What specifically additional information do you require?

Comment: @Damien A comprehensive picture, figuring out what's out there. This might include other search engines similar to Cordis, repositories countries not mentioned, tools that might assisst with gathering this information, figuring if there are schemes that share the successful submitted proposals...

Comment: @blackace I am not sure if there is a global directory, but there certainly should be.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**In the US,** the government funded agencies usually publish lists of funded projects. For example, you can search the [National Science Foundation](http://www.nsf.gov) database for all of the funded projects relating to ["beer"](http://www.nsf.gov/awardsearch/simpleSearchResult?queryText=beer&ActiveAwards=true). Each of these entries lists the name of the project, the NSF program that funded it, the PI's names and contact information, the amount awarded, the date awarded, and an abstract, among other information.

Here are the databases from other US government funding agencies:

- [National Endowment for the Arts](http://www.nea.gov/grants/recent/index.html)
- [National Endowment for the Humanities](https://securegrants.neh.gov/publicquery/main.aspx)
- [Environmental Protection Agency](http://yosemite.epa.gov/oarm/igms_egf.nsf/HomePage?ReadForm)
- [Department of Energy](http://science.energy.gov/funding-opportunities/award-search/)
- [National Institutes of Health](http://report.nih.gov/)

There are other agencies probably, but all you need to do is go to their main site and search for "funded projects" or "Search awards" or "recent awards" or something like that.

One agency that may be hard to search would be DARPA (Defense Advanced Research Projects Agency), which is the scientific research arm of US military.

Comment: so there is no unified meta search engine out there in US for all nationally funded projects. Any info on other countries?

Answer (score 7):

There are a couple of databases about funded research projects in the **Benelux** countries:

- [NARCIS - National Academic Research and Collaborations Information System](http://www.narcis.nl/?Language=en) (**NL**)
- [Fonds National de la Recherche](http://www.fnr.lu/en/Searchable-Project-Database/Research-Domain) (**LU**)
- [Databases INVENT and FEDRA by the Belgian Science Policy](http://www.belspo.be/belspo/research/data_en.stm) (**BE**)
- [Flanders Research Information Space](http://www.researchportal.be/en/projects/search.html) (**BE**)
- [Fonds de la Recherche Scientifique](http://www2.fnrs.be/) (**BE**, only in French)

In the **German speaking countries**, there are informative databases about funded reseach projects as well:

- [ELFI database for the German-speaking area](http://www.base.elfi.info/elfi-2.0/)
- [Swiss National Science Foundation](http://p3.snf.ch/) (**CH**)
- [FWF Austrian Science Fund](http://www.fwf.ac.at/en/projects/projekt_suche.html) (**AT**)
- [DFG German Research Foundation](http://gepris.dfg.de/gepris/OCTOPUS) (**DE**)

Comment: Welcome to this SE. I awarded the points to you as you provided the most interesting and diverse answers.

Answer (score 5):

In Australia, one of the main funding sources is [Discovery Projects](http://www.arc.gov.au/ncgp/dp/dp_outcomes.htm) from the [Australian Research Council](http://www.arc.gov.au/default.htm).  Another are [Cooperative Research Centres](https://www.crc.gov.au/Pages/default.aspx) - the website has several links attached to it.

Also, 'block grants' are allocated by the [Department of Industry, Innovation, Climate Change, Science, Research and Tertiary Education](http://www.innovation.gov.au/research/researchblockgrants/Pages/default.aspx) (yes, that is the department's real name).

Answer (score 5):

In France we have the [Agence Nationale de la Recherche](http://www.agence-nationale-recherche.fr/) (ANR, National Agency for Research). The "régions", local administrative divisions, have also a capacity to finance research.

Answer (score 4):

In India it is  [Shodh Gangotri](http://shodhgangotri.inflibnet.ac.in/).

From the website...

> The word “Shodh” originates from Sanskrit and stands for “research and discovery”. “Gangotri” is one of the largest glacier in the Himalayas and source of origination of Ganges, the holiest, longest and largest of rivers in India. The Ganges is the symbol of age-long culture, civilization, ever-aging, ever-flowing, ever-loving and loved by its people.
>
> ... research scholars / research supervisors in universities are requested to deposit electronic version of approved synopsis... The repository... would reveal the trends and directions of research being conducted in Indian universities [and] would avoid duplication of research. ...once the full-text thesis is submitted for a synopsis, a link to the full-text theses would be provided from ShodhGangotri to "ShodhGanga".

Comment: Why the down vote? The website seems like a legitimate answer to the question.

Comment: I agree with @DanielE.Shub. Would have been nice if a reason was provided for the down vote.